# R: Getting all dates a unique row occured and storing it in a variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am pulling data in a spark table and want to know the dates when a unique row occurred, and then storing these dates in a new variable. For example, if the data is:

```
ID     amt     status     date
A      1000    A          2019-01-01
A      1000    A          2019-02-01
B      1000    I          2019-01-01
B      3000    A          2019-02-01
B      3000    A          2019-03-01
```

I would like to see:

```
ID     amt     status    var
A      1000    A         2019-01-01|2019-02-01
B      1000    I         2019-01-01
B      3000    A         2019-02-01|2019-03-01
```

Thanks and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group_by(ID, amt, status)` and then `mutate` date to contain all dates separated by `|`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, amt, status) %>%
  mutate(date = paste(date, collapse = "|")) %>%
  distinct()
```

**Output**

```
  ID      amt status date                 
  <fct> <int> <fct>  <chr>                
1 A      1000 A      2019-01-01|2019-02-01
2 B      1000 I      2019-01-01           
3 B      3000 A      2019-02-01|2019-03-01
```

Or base R option:

```
aggregate(date ~ ID + amt + status, df, paste, collapse = "|")
```

Or `data.table`:

```
data.table(df)[,lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = "|"), .(ID, amt, status)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Although initially did not work, I looked it up and saw a workaround. https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/736

Answer (score 0):

can use `summarise`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, amt, status) %>%
  summarise(date = paste(date, collapse = "|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, amt, status) %>%
  mutate(date = str_c(date, collapse = "|")) %>%
  distinct()
```